# Firefox giving a 403 error with my site but works fine with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, ssl, iis

After I managed to publish my site and installed an SSL certificate and forced only using HTTPS with URL rewrite, I started testing to make sure it works without any problems.

It worked fine with Chrome but Firefox give me this error:

```
403 - Forbidden: Access is denied
```

So I went to the SSL settings in IIS and disabled requiring SSL. That made it work so I enabled it to see if the error will appear again but it didn't. The same exact thing happened with Internet Explorer.

Then I used a different computer and the same thing happened. It seems that if the browser gets access with it disabled it will always have access. 
Even setting it to ignore doesn't work, so what can I do just disable completely?

Comment: Without knowing the reason the browser thought the certificate was valid this question will be difficult to answer

Comment: I had an issue similar to this once. It was caused by mod_security settings on the server hosting the website. If mod_security is on in your server, try temporarily turning it off and see if the problem still happens,